# Change Chart Colours (bar) Based on Source Cell (using conditional formatting and VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add a button to change the colours on a bar chart given the source cell's colour.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim FormulaSplit As Variant
Dim SourceRangeColor As Long
Dim seriesArray() As Variant
Dim pointIterator As Integer

For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

    seriesArray = MySeries.Values
    For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)
        FormulaSplit = Split(MySeries.Formula, ",")
        SourceRangeColor = Range(FormulaSplit(2)).Item    (pointIterator).Interior.Color
        MySeries.Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = SourceRangeColor
      Next pointIterator
  Next MySeries
Next oChart

End Sub
```

It works perfectly fine if I fill in the respective cells myself, however if I set the cells to have their colour filled in via conditional formatting, the code above changes all the bars to white. I'm assuming it's because it is not reading the conditionally formatted cell fill, so it defaults to white.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting applied via CF can be accessed via the `DisplayFormat` property:

```
Range(FormulaSplit(2)).Item (pointIterator).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```